# HashRouter not working with useLocation()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use useLocation() but it is not working with HashRouter

I have a component that send some data to another route

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    if (index < questions[selected].length - 1) {
      setIndex((value) => value + 1);
    } else {
      history.push("/final", { selected, answer });
    }
  };
```

And on the route I have:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { selected, answer } = state;
```

But when I try to run the application it gives me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'selected' of 'state' as it is
> undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: Hash history does not support location.key or location.state.

Hence location.state is undefined with HashRouter